# How to order a list according to specific order?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists:
    `bigrams = ['apple pie', 'red vine', 'chicken salad']
        bigram_info = ['red vine 1', 'apple pie 0', 'chicken salad 2']`

I want to order bigram_info list according to bigrams list:
    `ordered_list = ['apple pie 0', 'red vine 1', 'chicken salad 2']`

I tried something but because of my lists are huge I didnt get correct result.

````
``` file=open("bigrams.txt","r")
    bigrams = file.read().splitlines()
    file.close()
    #print(bigrams)
    with open("bigram_info.txt", "r") as my_file:
            for line in my_file:
               words = line.split()
               words[0 : 2] = [' '.join(words[0 : 2])]
               for w in bigrams:
                      if  w==words[0]:
                             print(line)
````

````
When I run the code it prints that elements in order of bigram_info list.Like
    ``` bigram_info = ['red vine 1', 'apple pie 0', 'chicken salad 2']```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort `bigram_info` by the position of the first two words of each item in `bigram`, you can do it with this:

```py
sorted(bigram_info, key=lambda x: bigrams.index(' '.join(x.split()[:2])))
```